# Error in create table command- Incorrect syntax near

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I want to create a table name based on session's variable name

(session variable is email id of a student and sid of that student will be the table name which I want to create)

NOTE: sid is fetching fine..

Here's the code

```
SqlConnection con99 = new SqlConnection(con100);
con99.Open();
String email = Session["sname"].ToString();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id from students where email='" 
+ email + "'", con99);
sid = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); //as sid is int
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + sid + 
"(sno int, qpname nvarchar(500), mobtained int, tmarks int);", con99))
command.ExecuteNonQuery();        
con99.Close();
```

[image: here is the error message pic]

[image: variable sid is also being created-pic]

Comment: Don't you need a pair of ' ' around sid?  Like this, 'sid'...

Comment: @Brian i added "CREATE TABLE " + 'sid' + "(sno int, qpna........)

as u said and it shows error-Too many characters in character literal

Comment: Or, try, + "sid" + since you are casting it to a string already?

Comment: "sid" made a table named sid ... not by its value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put brackets around your table name if you are naming it with a number. So your script must end up like this when evaluated:

```
CREATE TABLE [2] (sno int, qpname nvarchar(500), mobtained int, tmarks int);
```

Frankly, I'm surprised that is allowed. It may be a feature of newer versions of SQL Server.

A better way to create database objects is with the SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) libraries. Much less chance to make syntax errors:

An example [from here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/154c19c4-95ba-4b6f-b6ca-479288feabfb/characters-that-are-not-allowed-in-table-name-column-name-in-sql-server-?forum=databasedesign)

```
Server srv = new Server("(local)");
Database db = srv.Databases["AdventureWorks2012"];

Table tb = new Table(db, "Test Table");
Column col1 = new Column(tb, "Name", DataType.NChar(50));
Column col2 = new Column(tb, "ID", DataType.Int);

tb.Columns.Add(col1); 
tb.Columns.Add(col2); 
tb.Create();
```

Comment: [2] is different.. i want to create a table naming the value of sid @Crowcoder

Comment: Using brackets is how you name things that do not follow naming standards. For instance, if you have a space in the name, or you use a number. You can't use just "2". It is impossible.

Comment: using this -     new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE" +[sid]+ "(sno int, q...  it gives an error  " Invalid expression term '['   "

Comment: wow! Crowcoder that worked! thanks a lot ..how to marks your answer correct now?

Answer (score 0):

First one is an error, next 2 are not:

```
create table 2 (id int)

create table [2] (id int)

create table ID_2 (id int)
```

See the section called "The first character must be one of the following"    [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx).

Comment: not understood what you are trying to say..
i want a table naming value of sid not 2 @JBrooks